# Angular Material Icons animation

Tags: angular, material-design

Have you any idea how to make transition state ON/OFF on material icons ?

Same question for the other animations (bouncing for example)

https://material.io/design/iconography/animated-icons.html

[image]

[image]

Comment: Whats the question here?

Comment: Have you any idea how to make transition state ON/OFF on material icons ?

Comment: Do you want to know how to transition in material icons? Have you tried anything yet/

Comment: The link you have posted is just a guidline for material design. How you implement is totally up to you. Each transition will required to write code. can you be specific, which animation is that u are referring?

Comment: @Plochie the documentation does not describe how to use it. Even if it is required to write code how and what code need to be written?